# SwiftyJSON alway return nil value when parser data

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I used SwiftyJSON in my project to parser a local json file.

1. I put json data in a string and read by SwiftJSON and It works very well
2. I put json data to file then try to read it again but I alway get nil.

This is my code.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("restaurants", ofType: "json")
print(path)
let jsonData = JSON(NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!)
print(jsonData.rawString())

let resultNSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)
let resultNSString = NSString(data: resultNSData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
print(resultNSString)



let s = "{\"entryID\": 1,\"from\": \"String\",\"to\": \"String\",\"value\": \"String\"}"

if let data = s.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    let j = JSON(data:data)
    print("endtryeID \(j["entryID"].int)")
    print("endtryeID2 \(j["from"].string)")
}
```

Comment: What is `nil`? `path`?  `jsonData.rawString()`?

Comment: What does print(resultNSString) display?

Comment: print(jsonData.rawString()) alway return nil. path is true and resultNSString  also is true.